# how to match text limiting it with not condition

Tags: php, regex

I have one problem in understanding regex

For example i have following text:

```
To ask Jack the Daniels, John the Ripper, whether, they will go out.
```

And I want to match this part - `Jack the Daniels, John the Ripper`, it ends with comma and lowercase letters after it (, [a-z])*

When I match it with this regex:

```
'To ask (?P<addressee>[A-Za-z,\s]*), [a-z]'
```

I get following result:

```
Jack the Daniels, John the Ripper, whether
```

So question is can I use not condition inside parenthesis? Something like this, but it not works for me:

```
'To ask (?P<addressee>[A-Za-z,\s]*(^, [a-z]*)), [a-z]'
```

----EDIT

Seems if i will match it with something like this:
    '(\W[A-Z].*?),'
and use preg_match_all I will get what I want, but text can be like following too:

```
To ask Jack the Daniels, John the Ripper, whether, they will go out with Joe the Man, or me.
```

And I will match `Joe the Man` too, which I don't want to. Do I need to use before condition to check is there a (, [a-z]) before match?

Following don't work, how to correct it?

```
'(?<!(, [a-z]))(\W[A-Z].*?),'
```

Comment: I'm testing it here http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: You want to match whole string `Jack the Daniels, John the Ripper` ?

Comment: yes, from "To ask" until the first comma with lower case letters after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
'(\W[A-Z].*?),'
```

Also tested `@www.spaweditor.com`

-- EDIT

With `'\W([A-Z].*?),\W[a-z]'` and `preg_match` you will capture first result.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Maybe you also can explain why it capture all text? I don't see repetition marks but it captures even `Jack the Daniels, John the Ripper, John the Ripper` when I adding one more contact. Or it all explained in, for example, Jeffrey Friedl book? If so, I think I will read it when possible.

Comment: `\W[A-Z]` - it matches text that is started with whitespace and capital letter: ` J` . Then `.*?` matches every character with condition (using condition defined as `?`) that it should stop matching characters if it finds `,\W[a-z]`